# declaring new array in ES6? what is this doing

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me what this is doing?

```
[blog.id]: blog
```

I'm assuming it's creating a new array with `blog.id` as one element with an example id/key of 4, and blog is the content set equal to this element.

```
 export default function(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_BLOG:
          const blog = action.payload;
          return { ...state, [blog._id]: blog };
        case FETCH_BLOGS:
          return { ...state, ...mapKeys(action.payload, '_id') };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's a computed property key: [Computed property names (ES2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Nope it is assigning the `blog` object to the `blog_id` property in the state object. if the `blog._id` contains `123` as value, the state = state = {..., 123: [object]}

Comment: It'd be easy enough to actually *check* what it's doing because it's code and you can run it, either locally (browser like Chrome, NodeJS) or an [online ES6 REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl). That way you don't have to assume, you'd just know. You might still have to figure out what it's *called*, but at least you wouldn't have to assume what the *outcome* was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a computed property key: [Computed property names (ES2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and [Object Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).

It creates a new Object with all the key/values that `state` has (that's what `...state` does) with a key whose name is the resolution of the property `blog._id` and whose value is `blog`.

So if `blog._id` is `"foo"` and `blog` is `"bar"`,

The object returned is:

```
{
  "all": "the",
  "key": "vals",
  "state": "had",

  // along with the new key/val
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: clear answer with a great example. great explanation thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's new more convenient ES6 syntax:

```
c:\srv> node                    
> blog = {_id:42}               
{ _id: 42 }
```

This doesn't work:

```
> {blog._id: blog}              
({blog._id: blog})              
      ^                         

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

but enclosing it in `[]` does:

```
> {[blog._id]: blog}            
{ '42': { _id: 42 } }
```

the other syntax is dict unpacking.  Let's make two variables:

```
> a = 1; b = 2                  
2
```

instead of `c = {a:a, b:b}` you can write

```
> c = {a, b}                    
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

and the `...` lets you copy all attributes from the dict:

```
> {...c}                        
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

so this line

```
return { ...state, [blog._id]: blog };
```

copies everything from the `state` object and adds a field with key `blog._id` and value `blog`.  It's similar to

```
const res = {};
for (const attr of state) {
    res[attr] = state[attr];
}
res[blog._id] = blog;
return res;
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, explained it, but above answer was clearer with a better example.